# PdfFilePrinter print from client

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, printing

I have web server and a network printer.

from the web server, I successfully print through visual studio only..somehow, i can't print if i am running it from IIS in the same server.

this is my code to do the printing

```
    Process printjob = new Process();

    printjob.StartInfo.FileName = physicalPath + @"\test\" + filename;

    printjob.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";

    printjob.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    printjob.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

    PrinterSettings setting = new PrinterSettings();

    setting.PrinterName = printerName;

    setting.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;

    printjob.Start();
```

shall i need to configure IIS or else to ensure i cant print it from the IIS?..please help me

Thanks

Comment: Have you installed the printer on the IIS server? Does the user that your IIS is running under have permissions to print to that server?

Comment: @BerndLinde yes and i have try print it directly from the visual studio and its works.. but i try to print from the server browser itself where the printer driver installed, its not working. I believe it shall have a privilege to print since i run directly from the same user

Comment: Hhmm, your `settings` object is never linked to your `printjob`. Is that intended?  Also the Filename that you give `physicalPath + @"\test\" + filename`, does that exist on the server and what is that?

Comment: Yeah..the file is exists in the server..its a PDF file with a full path..i do test with the visual studio directly and successful..on then if i do running from the server localhost its failed.. :(

Comment: Do you have an exception that you can show or any error message?

Comment: i worries there is no show any exception error message..i try put all the code inside try and catch block..but it never fired the exception..

Comment: Have a look at your EventLog, there should be an error there. Without an error or an indication as to what is going wrong, we can't really give more recommendations.

Comment: @BerndLinde where shall i look for the EventLog for IIS?.. i never know about this features.. T_T... i try to go in the administrative tools and event viewer..but i dunno which one is IIS log..

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524984%28v=vs.90%29.aspx